# Run method when Android Alarm goes off

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarms

I have made an app that talks over Sockets to a Raspberry Pi.  The app just sends open/close message to the Raspberry Pi which in turn opens or closes my blinds.  I want to add a setting to the app that will automatically open the blinds when an alarm goes off.  The alarm will be set using the default android alarm app.

So if I set an alarm in the android alarm app/clock app, I want to invoke some of my code when the alarm goes off.

I'm a beginner programmer and don't know where to start so any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I'm little rusty in android, but I believe what you are looking for is a "broadcast receiver". Not sure if exists on for alarm app/clock app.

Comment: plus 1 You can create a background service that listens for an Alarm.